# USB drive error SCSI cache

Tags: mount, fstab, usb-drive, cache, scsi

just recognized an unknown error, as i checked my actual log with `journalctl -f`.

When i unmounted my Backup-USB-disk with `unmount /path/to/disk` and then pulled the cable out, a short noise occured inside the USB-disk (like hard-shutdown your PC by holding Powerbutton long). Wasn’t the first time.

I checked the log and found following lines:

```
Aug 04 11:20:12 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 04 11:20:12 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 04 11:20:12 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
(...)
Aug 04 11:18:38 flo-mika-gulfi systemd[1]: home-flo-backup\x2dusb.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 04 11:17:50 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel:  sda: sda1
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
Aug 04 11:17:37 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi mtp-probe[8391]: bus: 4, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi mtp-probe[8391]: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1"
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi mtp-probe[8390]: bus: 4, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi mtp-probe[8390]: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1"
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     KESU     USB 3.0          0209 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: scsi host2: uas
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: usb 4-1: SerialNumber: DD564198838A2
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: usb 4-1: Manufacturer: KESU
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: usb 4-1: Product: USB 3.0
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0583, bcdDevice= 2.09
Aug 04 11:17:34 flo-mika-gulfi kernel: usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

Does anybody know, what this is about? Searched the Web on a quick try, but couldn’t find a fitting solution; just that it may be a bad sign for my USB-drive.

The `/etc/fstab` entry looks like this:

`UUID=10235a64-232a-4834-ccdd-bccf8f8fe3d6 /path/to/disk ext4 defaults,noauto,noatime,user 0 0`

I already tried **sync** option, but didn't changed anything.

Would be nice to know, because the USB-drive is used on my daily Cron-job for backing up my home directory with different snapshots. The USB-drive is only a few years old and was seldomly used until last month, when it became my backup-disk.

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: I've seen this when the USB is diconnected before the `umount` has finished.  The USB device is disconnected before the cache has been written. Normally, `umount` will flush the cache. You could try the `sync` command (not the option)  before the `umount` .

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. I also thought about this possibility, because after unmounting the USB it sounds like it keeps working---but for about 20-30 minutes. This seems a bit long to write the cache.

Comment: First waited until the working noise stopped and disconnected the cable. The peeping noise wasn't heard, but the error-messages were the same as mentioned in the quesiton. Then just tried your advice, Lim, using `sync` command first, but it didn't worked out as well. Creepy disk-dying noise and usual error-message...
Is there another possibility or reason? Maybe because the filesystem is **ext4**? Actually, i don't want to buy a new USB-storage, for backing up my system...